# Need an algorithm to print a list of unique words and number of occurences

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, brute-force, divide-and-conquer

I need to create a program that inputs an English language text file and outputs a list of words contained in the file and the number of occurrences. I need to make one using a brute force method and one with divide and conquer.
I will code it myself so please don't give me code, but I need help figuring out how to go about doing it - basically what is the algorithm behind each method, especially the divide and conquer? Pseudo code would be great

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part of this you need help with and what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Using a brute force method:**

Create a list that stores word (say, `key`) and corresponding counter for their occurrences(say `cnt`). Traverse through the file and :

1. if the word is not present, append it in the list and start the counter as `cnt = 1`.
2. if the word is present, do `cnt++`.

**Using divide and conquer:**

1. Use separate list for each starting alphabet (a to z). So there would be at most 26 separate lists.
2. Traverse through the list. For each word, pick up the starting character and choose the corresponding list to search the word. Then, perform the *search and update* method used in brute force method.

*Note: None of them are optimized. They perform poorly against hashmap implementation.*